# Contact form: recipient from node's Email field

Tags: nodes, forms, 8, emails

**Use case:** Business Directory.
**Description:** I need to create a dynamic contact form that will use each node's (business listing content type) individual Email field as the contact form's main recipient, or at least as a carbon copy ('CC').

I have spent 2 days looking for modules as well as various coding suggestions from around the web with no success.
Example: [Contact for per node in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196293/contact-for-per-node-in-drupal-8)

This was easily accomplished in D7 with

> Views Contact Form

module. However, it doesn't yet work with D8.

I'm using a clean installation of Drupal 8.1. 
I don't know yet how to create a custom module, but will learn if needed. Ideally, a `.theme file` based solution would be easy for me to implement.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!